# Find the set of $k \geq 3$ satifying $(k-2)|2k$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As a starting point, a solution claims that finding $k$ such that $(k-2)|2k$ is equivalent to finding $k$ such that $gcd(k-2,2k) = k - 2$.

Why is this true?

I can coherently post the rest, for the benefit of all future users, once I understand how this fact fits into the solution!

Comment: For any natural numbers $a,b$, if $a|b$ then $\gcd(a,b)=a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\gcd(k - 2, 2k) = k - 2$, then using the division algorithm, it must also be true that $$\gcd(k-2,4) = k - 2$$  This is obtained from using the euclidean division algorithm to have $2k = 2*(k-2)+ 4$

If $\gcd(k-2,4) = k - 2$, then $k - 2$ must divide $4$, implying that $k - 2$ is amongst the factors $(1,2,4)$. This gives the solution for acceptable values of $k$.

Answer (score 1):

$2k=(k-2)p$ $,p \in \mathbb{Z},$ now $\gcd(k-2,2k)|(k-2)$ and $\gcd(k-2,2k)|2k$ then if $(k-2)|2k,$ $\gcd(k-2,2k)=k-2$. You can complement this with the Bèzout's Lemma.